# Frontend edit not working - "ReferenceError: Joomla is not defined"

Tags: front-end, editing

When i try to edit my posts in the joomla frontend i get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Joomla is not defined
```

I can open the posts editor in the frontend, change the content and when i want to save it i get another error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Joomla is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

How can i solve this problem? Looks like a script or something is missing. Im using Joomla Version 3.6.4, use a frontend built from scratch and my admin template is isis.

Answer (score 1):

There can be javascript cache problems. 
Clear your browser/Joomla! cache first: 
https://docs.joomla.org/Help36:Site_Maintenance_Clear_Cache 
http://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser's-Cache 
If that won't help simply reinstall Joomla! Keep in mind that all your CSS changes will override during reinstallation.

Comment: Thx for your help. I clearad all the cache. Nothing changed. I think also a joomla reinstall will not change this. Someone told me it could be that mootools ins not loaded. Now i try to load mootools with joomla. I added "('behavior.framework')" and also installed a plugin to load mootools. Actually its doing nothing (not loading mootools). Going crazy about this...

Comment: As for mootols plugin, have you tried: plg_j25_legacy.zip plugin?